# How to Find Last month's Last week's First Day using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I am at december month now and I want to find november month's first day of the last week. So How can I find? using jquery

Comment: jQuery is not a date processing library.

Comment: Do you need last 7th day of the month?.. first day of any week is could be sunday or monday..!

Comment: Is third-party an option? If so, I would recommend _moment_.

Comment: its very simple. Just go to last day of last month. Check whether its a monday or not. If its a monday; then thats your required day. If its not monday then simply go to previous day by -1 and check for Monday till you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no need to use jQuery to solve your question.

Here is a Gist [GetWeeksInMonth.js](https://gist.github.com/markthiessen/3883242) that get weeks in a month as array of start and end days.

Code:

```js
var d = new Date(),
    month, 
    year, 
    weeks = [],
    lastMonthLastWeekFirstDay;

// Substract one month
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

month = d.getMonth();
year = d.getYear();

// Note: month is 0 based, just like Dates in js
function getWeeksInMonth(month, year) {
  var weeks = [],
      firstDate = new Date(year, month, 1),
      lastDate = new Date(year, month + 1, 0),
      numDays = lastDate.getDate(),
      start = 1,
      end = 7 - firstDate.getDay();

  while (start <= numDays) {
    weeks.push({
      start: start,
      end: end
    });
    start = end + 1;
    end = end + 7;
    if (end > numDays) {
      end = numDays;
    }
  }
  return weeks;
}

weeks = getWeeksInMonth(month, year);
lastMonthLastWeekFirstDay = weeks[weeks.length - 1].start;

console.log(lastMonthLastWeekFirstDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is your best friend!

```
moment()
    .subtract(1,'months')
    .endOf('month')
    .startOf('week')
    .format(/* YYYY-MM-DD */)
```